# The object's height sets to 0 - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layout, components

I am a beginner in Unity and I am currently making a simple game. I recently solved my problem of scrolling two objects at the same time, but the vertical layout will put the other at the bottom. The answer came from the question I posted a while ago which is to use `LayoutElement` component. It does work in general, but when I start or play in the Unity it does not work at the start, I need to disable it and enable at runtime for it to work.

Just to add, I noticed that the `ObjectiveItem` object is 0 everytime I start or play the project. And the height will set to its children's height when I disable and enable the `LayoutElement` component.

I think the `Content Size Fitter` sets the height to 0. because when I mess with any height related settings in like when I uncheck the height value in `Child Force Expand` it will set the height to the height of its children same goes to the `Child Force Expand` of the `Lines` and `Items` objects. And like I mentioned in the start, when I disable and enable the `LayoutElement` in the `ObjectiveItem` object it will set the height of the children or even when setting the object itself inactive and active. The main problem is that the `height` is set to 0 at the start of the game.

[image]

This is the object (`ObjectiveItem`) that is set to the Content of the `ScrollRect`. The object already has `Vertical Layout Group` and `Content Size Fitter` to get the height of its children.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Start instead of Awake?

Comment: @hijinxbassist yes I've tried using Start instead of Awake. The script is just for adding object for increasing the height of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this combination of a `LayoutGroup` + `ContentSizeFitter` you should also enable the `XYLayoutGroup.ControlChildSize` and not use `Force Expand` and then your child objects should either have a `ContentSizeFitter` (if it is further `LayoutGroup`s) themselves or have a `LayoutElement` with according settings.

I know this feels extremely clunky but this is the way I was told and worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want scroll to work on new items you need to have a `VerticalLayoutGroup` that also has a `ContentSizeFitter` component with preferred height chosen, that way new items will increase the height of the vertical layout and if added correctly to the scroll component it will scroll with any height.

Comment: I already have those components. The problem is when I start or play in the Unity the height will be set to 0 and not the children's height.

Comment: Is the `ContentSizeFitter` has the type as `PreferredHeight`? The elements inside must not have a contents size fitter themselves, their height should be fixed for better results.